# Is there a labor vs leisure model with work experience?

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, labor-economics, optimization, model

I find the labor-leisure model with utility functions interesting, but I find it lacks the factor of work experience, which is very important in the real life labor market.

This is a reason people why people might start working for a lower wage or even do unpaid internships.

I tried searching for a labor-leisure model including the work experience factor in the internet but had no luck.

I remember doing the following linear regression model in econometrics:

$\log(Wage_{it}) = \alpha + \beta \cdot \log(Experience_{it}) + \epsilon_{it}$

So maybe we could solve for the wage here and plug into the usual budget constraint?

By exponentiating, we get

$w_t = w_0 {E_t}^\beta$

where $w_0 := e^\alpha$ and $E_t$ is experience, which we could define as $E_t = \sum_{k=1}^{t} L_k$ (the total amount of time worked in the agent’s lifetime)?

With this we would get

$\max \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t [U(c_t, l_t)]$

subject to

$w_0 (\sum_{k=1}^{t} L_k)^\beta + (1+r_{t+1}) s_t = c_t + s_{t+1}$

Here $l_t := T - L_t$ is leisure, where $T$ is the time endowment on each period.

I would appreciate any insight on an extension of this kind.

Comment: I dont have time for full answers but there are models with experience, one example: https://www.jstor.org/stable/145087?casa_token=J2qADYf4mCMAAAAA%3AtAOMkRlv1ILTPXrrFXsu16jGv6Bqc15-K_PIKk2huMp0-br9W_xj78vhVXv8i9nIPEBbPP__P7lc-wXIGHMD2FWVDmQL8Jr0eiEAAVXuMe5iskE16dMR

Comment: @1muflon1 Thank you! I'll check the paper when I have time.